# NSURLConnection always connects to the same URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

Whenever I create an NSURLConnection in a class I have, it always connects to the first URL connected to by that class. It has an ivar `conn` that the NSURLConnection is stored in, and here is the method that connects:

```
-(void)getMoreProblems
{
    problemsPage++;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://projecteuler.net/problems;page=%d",problemsPage]];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%p",conn);
    conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%p",conn);
}
```

I have checked by `NSLog`ing the URL's description and the Connection's pointer that they are different, as well as telling the UIApplication to load the URL in safari. As far as I can tell, It tries to load the right page. I also tried both POST and GET, but it didn't make a difference. What might be causing this?

**EDIT FOR ANYONE LOOKING AT THIS WITH A SIMILAR PROBLEM:**

My problem ended up being that I did not reinitialize the `NSMutableData` I stored the connection data in after each page loaded.

Comment: It always connects to page 1, even if problemsPage==2, unless I set problemsPage to something else at the beginning, in which case it always connects to that page.

Comment: So `url` is definitely getting updated to page=2 then?  if you NSLog it right before the `NSURLRequest` gets created?  Are you receiving the `didFinish...` delegate calls from the first `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: Are you sure the previous connection has completed before you start the next - how are you differentiating?  What do you do with the completed request?

Comment: `url` was being NSLogged and even sent to safari right before the request was created. It definitely has page=2. This won't get called again until The `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method has been called and the data put in a UITableView. for the record, I have checked in that method and the pointer to an `NSURLConnection` it gets sent is equal to `conn`.

Comment: do you do `conn=nil;`  in your `connectionDidFinishLoading`?

Comment: @JustinPaulson It didn't help (I just tried it)

Comment: Could this be a problem with caching?  Maybe try using requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: with a cachePolicy of NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

Comment: @rdelmar just tried that. still doesn't work. thanks though

Comment: What do mean by "it always connects to the first URL"?  How are you seeing this?  Ae you loading the page that you get, and it's always the same?  How and where are you loading it (do you have a web view?)?

Comment: My program, upon receiving page 2's data, adds it to the table view after the rest of the data. It re-adds the first page's data when I tell it to get the next page. (where the second should be). hen I sort it, I get to copies of the same thing side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but it's too long for a comment. I can't see anything wrong with the code that you posted.  I pasted your code for getMoreProblems into a new project and added the delegate methods necessary to look at the results -- as far as I can tell it worked fine.  I can see in the resulting string, the problem numbers starting with 1 on the first page I receive (from the first call to getMoreProblems) and starting with problem 51 on the second call to getMoreProblems.  The only thing I added to your getMoreProblems method was the if-else clause at the end.  HEre is the code I used:

```
@synthesize window = _window,receivedData;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    problemsPage = 0;
    [self getMoreProblems];
}


-(void)getMoreProblems {
    problemsPage++;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://projecteuler.net/problems;page=%d",problemsPage]];
    NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%p",conn);
    conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"%p",conn);
    if (conn) {
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"The Connection Failed");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%@",response.URL);
    [self.receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"In connection:didReceiveData:");
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}



- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %lu bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    NSString *page = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",page);
    [self performSelector:@selector(getMoreProblems) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

So, I can't reproduce your problem -- I'm guessing it lies elsewhere in some code that you didn't post.

Comment: I found the problem - It was outside that method;I was using an NSMutableData to store the data from the NSURLConnection and I wasn't resetting or recreating it when making a new connection.